# Recommended local search optimization algorithm for control domain

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

**Background:** I am trying to find a *list of floating point parameters* for a low level controller that will lead to balance of a robot while it is walking.

**Question:** Can anybody recommend me any local search algorithms that will perform well for the domain I just described? The main *criteria* for me is the speed of convergence to the right solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**P.S.** Also, I conducted some research and found out that "Evolutianry
Strategy" algorithms are a good fit for continuous state space. However, I am not entirely sure, if they will fit well my particular problem.

**More info:** I am trying to optimize 8 parameters (although it is possible for me to reduce the number of parameters to 4). I do have a simulator and a criteria for me is speed in number of trials because simulation resets are costly (take 10-15 seconds on average).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best local search algorithms for low number of dimensions (up to about 10 or so) is the [Nelder-Mead simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method). By the way, it is used as the default optimizer in MATLAB's [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) function. I personally used this method for finding parameters of some textbook 2nd or 3rd degree dynamic system (though very simple one).

Other option are the already mentioned evolutionary strategies. Currently the best one is the Covariance Matrix Adaption ES, or [CMA-ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES). There are variations to this algorithm, e.g. BI-POP CMA-ES etc. that are probably better than the vanilla version.

You just have to try what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to evolutionary algorithm, I recommend you also check reinforcement learning.

The right method depends a lot on the details of your problem. How many parameters? Do you have a simulator? Do you work in simulation only, or also with real hardware? Speed is in number of trials, or CPU time?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I just edited my original question and added that info as well.